How to create single column 3x1 plot in a 3x2 subplot?
I want to create a plot with 2 columns, with the 1st one has only 1 plot and the 2nd one has 3. I try to set it up by using the following code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def format_axes(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2 = plt.subplot(224)
ax3 = plt.subplot(121)
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3]
format_axes(fig)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

But then I struggle to make 4th plot because subplot doesn't support index > 5, and I don't know how to make each plot figure size satisfies the given proportion.
I tried again using gridspec by using the code below
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

def format_axes(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")

gs = GridSpec(3, 2, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[: , 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, -1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, 1])
format_axes(fig)

plt.show()

However, my problem arises again because I couldn't manipulate each plot's size.
Is there a universal way to make a column size plot for bigger nrows x ncols subplots? And could someone explain gridspec for me, I copied the code from matplotlib.org and changed some values.

What about the plot size are you trying to adjust?

I'm trying to make the 1st plot to be 3x1, and 1x1 for the rest. I've achieved this with the 1st attempt, but it didn't have the number of plot I need. I want to know if there is any way to specify each plot's size, and to make one plot a whole column (or row).

Doesn't the second code give you that?

The 2nd code gave me 3 plots on the 2nd column which have 1x2 size.

I don't understand what that means. The second code gives you three plots in a column on the right and one plot on the left that extends the same height as the right plots. But that's not what you want?

Not sure which layout exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you're new to this I think that plt.subplot_mosaic might be easier, tweaking axes' sizes with height_ratios and widths_ratios.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    """
    AB
    AC
    AD
    """,
    constrained_layout=True,
    height_ratios=[1, 3, 2],
    width_ratios=[1, 2],
)

# axd is a dict of Axes, e.g. use axd["A"]

def label_axes(axd):
    for ax_name, ax in axd.items():
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, ax_name, va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

label_axes(axd)

fig.show()



Note that if what you was searching for were the height_ratios and width_ratios arguments, those are actually arguments for GridSpec down the line.
